# How to display in browser python output trough javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Thanks to this script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import sys  
import urlparse
import io

url = "anUrl"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
div = soup.find('div',id='content')
print div.prettify().encode(sys.stdout.encoding, 'ignore')
```

i've scraped some content that i want to print into another html page, trough javascript how can i handle the python output? Is it possible to print the content in the same way i've done in command line, with a browser page? I've got some encoding problems trying to do that.

Comment: I don't see how Javascript will help you write a new HTML file using Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to write the div to an HTML file, then you basically do just that.

```
f = open('file.html', 'w')
f.write(div)
f.close()
```